# Batchfile to save one line of text

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im trying to make a script that saves a user text input were it can type its disered database name and after that he pressed enter and it will be saved as Userconfig.txt to the fixed location.

I need this for a other program to get the database name the user wants.

So basicly it has to be that the user only has to type its pc name and the others settings are fixed.

Anyone able to help me?

```
REM check 
if not ["%ProgramW6432%"]==[""] ( 
    set "pf=%ProgramFiles(x86)%" 
) else ( 
  set pf="%ProgramFiles%"
)
REM USE
@echo ??textinput?? >> "%pf%\B4ict\IQ-Soft\Userconfig.txt"
```

Comment: You're missing a `%` at the end of `%ProgramFiles(x86)`

Comment: (Or at least, I assume that's your problem; you say you have a problem and then don't actually say what it is. The missing percent sign was just the thing that popped out at me.)

Comment: excuse me didnt ment to say problem.

Comment: Well then I have no idea at all what you're asking.

Comment: Writing to `%ProgramFiles%` or to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` should raise the `Access is denied` error

Comment: are you aware of the existing environment variables `%computername%` and `%username%`? (better than asking the user for already existing information))

Comment: updated question, ment to say desired server name instead of computer name. Need this for a other program so it can get the name from the userconfig.txt

Comment: You need to use quotes in for your set commands `set  "pf=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"` and `set "pf=%ProgramFiles%"` to avoid problems with closing brackets in the path names

Comment: @JosefZ it will be runned as admin to avoid that error

Comment: @jeb, thanks for pointing that out eddited it :)

Comment: `>>` instead of `>` to keep others settings unchanged in `Userconfig.txt`. However, you should check the server _existence_ as user's input could be erroneous.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, but how can i make it that "??textinput??" can be eddited by the user and the other settings are fixed? So basicly if i run the script it will ask what database name i want and the other settings will always be kept?

Comment: Wait, is the entire point of this question just to figure out how to store user input in a variable?

Comment: basicly yeah, but i want it so that it only shows someting like, what database name do u want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all chat:

```
REM check 
if not ["%ProgramW6432%"]==[""] ( 
    set "pf=%ProgramFiles(x86)%" 
) else ( 
  set "pf=%ProgramFiles%"
)
rem input
set /P "textinput=type your desired database name and hit <Enter>: "

rem check to ensure user input is valid database name here

REM USE
@echo %textinput% >> "%pf%\B4ict\IQ-Soft\Userconfig.txt"
```